# what data sets can rectifier linear unit classify?

Tags: deep-learning

I am trying to look at the possible activation functions for deep network for speaker recognition. I will have an input and a label (0s and 1s)as an output. I was wondering if rectifier linear unit (ReLu) can be used with any type of output or just specific one ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Activation functions are normally only used in the hidden layers. Output units almost always have a linear activation function (ie identity or no activation function). Rectified units are used in the hidden layers because their gradient is much simpler than their sigmoidal counterparts which allows for better training with many layers.

You mentioned your output has labels as either 0s or 1s is this an output vector with N outputs that are either 0 or 1? Or do you mean that you have only 2 classes (0 or 1). If you want to do classification (getting the network to output either class 0 or class 1) you would use Softmax activation on the output layer. Softmax scales the output to be a probability of the network's predicted class.

Let me know more information and I will see if I can help more.

Comment: Thank you. The output i have is for 20 classes.So that output matrix has 20 cols (since it is 20 subjects) and 1000 rows. So, when the row (- the values) correspond to the subject, those row/cols have a value of 1 otherwise 0. I hope that makes sense. So , it this case, could i use sigmoid or identity function for the output layer or would you suggest anything else? Thank you

Comment: Is there a case where you want the network to output more than one class? Otherwise it looks like you are using a common 'one-hot' setup. Where your output vector contains a 1 in the correct index for the class and zeros everywhere else. If so, definitely use a Softmax activation function for your output nodes. Also make sure to use categorical cross-entropy for your training error.